# Genexus - Gam - Deploy

Tags: genexus

Tengo un App en Gx 15 U4 y SD Android y .NET con SQL Server.

Estoy preparando la base de datos para llevarla a otro PC..La BD tendrá otro nombre al actual, para lo cual estoy armando todo en la máquina local.

A nivel de las preferencias del modelo cambie el nombre de la Base de Datos de la App y automáticamente me lo cambió en GAM también al mismo repositorio.

Hice un Create Database y me creo todo, lo mismo hice desde Tools para el GAM. Dentro de la base ahora tengo las tablas del sistema mas las de GAM. En el momento de correr el Tool de GAM, supuestamente inicializó todo lo necesario.

Ahora cuando ejecuto la App en la máquina de siempre, solicita el Login de la App y al entrar me da un error controlado que dice: que no existe el Usuario y Password de GAM, que consulte con el Administrador.

Si vuelvo a dejar la preferencia con la base de datos anterior funciona bien.

¿Que es bien lo que sucede y que debo cambiar?

Estuve viendo que hay algunos comentarios en SAC's que dice que debo indicar el Usuario y Password pero no estoy seguro donde. Si es en las preferencias del Modelo a nivel de GAM o en otro lado.

Muchas gracias por sus comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de crear la base de datos nueva con las preferencias nuevas hay que hacer un rebuild all.

De esa manera se genera el `connection.gam` nuevamente y se comienza a conectar bien a esa BD.

Otra alternativa es correr en el menú `Tools->GeneXus Access Manager` las opciones:

- Initialize metadata
- Update Connection File

Ten en cuenta que los datos de conexión y de administrador ingresados en las preferencias de la base de datos son los utilizados a la hora de crear la misma.

Tu usuario administrador va a ser el que fue colocado en esa propiedad.